# Conda stopped working

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I was installing pymc through conda, and it told me to update a few of the files so no problem. However, after updating, it gave an OSError, and now, I cannot access any conda build commands. Now, when I type any conda command, it gives me

```
-bash: conda: command not found
```

I checked the bash_profile, and .bashrc, and both have the appropriate PATH for conda, and most modules installed through conda still works. Running python and checking the version yields

```
Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda custom (x86_64)
```

Looking at the ~/anaconda/bin, I see that the conda folder is not there. Is there anyway to fix this? Is the only solution to re-install anaconda?

Sorry, I do not have any of the terminal outputs since I closed all my windows. Also, I didn't realize I was running Jupyter notebook in the background, but this shouldn't have a problem. Jupyter no longer runs, and yields the error

```
[W 01:34:35.979 NotebookApp] Unrecognized JSON config file version, assuming version 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/kaichang/anaconda/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 6, in <module>
sys.exit(notebook.notebookapp.main())
File "/Users/kaichang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "/Users/kaichang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 595, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
File "/Users/kaichang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 74, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/kaichang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1069, in initialize
self.init_configurables()
File "/Users/kaichang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 837, in init_configurables
parent=self,
File "/Users/kaichang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nb_conda_kernels/manager.py", line 19, in __init__
specs = self.find_kernel_specs() or {}
File "/Users/kaichang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nb_conda_kernels/manager.py", line 129, in find_kernel_specs
self.conda_info = self._conda_info()
File "/Users/kaichang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nb_conda_kernels/manager.py", line 29, in _conda_info
p = subprocess.check_output(["conda", "info", "--json"]
File "/Users/kaichang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
File "/Users/kaichang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/Users/kaichang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Sorry, I'm just not entirely sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looking at the ~/anaconda/bin, I see that the conda folder is not
>   there. Is there anyway to fix this?

In answer to this, you can try overwriting your conda installation:

```
bash /path/to/Miniconda2-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh -bfp /Users/kaichang/anaconda/
```

Comment: This worked -- could I ask what this particularly means? Does it meant to run the script, which forces Miniconda to re-install in the same directory, overwriting any changes made to native conda packages?

Comment: Yes, that's what it does.